# ansible: call same role with differents vars in a playbook

Tags: ansible

I try to control from one unique playbook the call of the same role n times with n different vars:

```
---
- hosts: myhost
  vars:
    user: user1
    virtualenv: venv_nameV3
  roles:
    - makeuser
    - stack  # use virtualenv var so stack role is installed in venv_nameV3      
    - stack  # should need it's own virtualenv value e.g. venv_nameV4
    - stack  # should need it's own virtualenv value e.g. venv_nameV5
    - stack  # should need it's own virtualenv value e.g. venv_nameV6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parameterise roles by adding variables using the following syntax

```
---
- hosts: myhost
  vars:
    user: user1
    virtualenv: default_venv_name
  roles:
    - makeuser
    - { role: stack, virtualenv: 'venv_nameV3' }
    - { role: stack, virtualenv: 'venv_nameV4' }
    - { role: stack, virtualenv: 'venv_nameV5' }
    - { role: stack, virtualenv: 'venv_nameV6' }
```

Comment: Is there any non-json way to do this? I tried experimenting with a few but to no avail. Json-style is OK but it feels a little ugly inside the Playbook.

Comment: @fquinner You cannot insert a proper code block as a comment, so I created a separate answer.

Comment: Could I include_vars different files for the same role?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert a proper code block as a comment, so here is the accepted answer written in pure YAML instead of JSON:

**My initial answer turns out not to be correct. Here is the corrected one:**

```
---

- hosts: myhost
  vars:
    user: user1
    virtualenv: default_venv_name
  roles:
    - makeuser
    - role: stack
      virtualenv: venv_nameV3
    - role: stack
      virtualenv: venv_nameV4
    - role: stack
      virtualenv: venv_nameV5
    - role: stack
      virtualenv: venv_nameV6
```

**Original answer:**

```
---

- hosts: myhost
  vars:
    user: user1
    virtualenv: default_venv_name
  roles:
    - makeuser
    - role: stack
      vars:
        virtualenv: venv_nameV3
    - role: stack
      vars:
        virtualenv: venv_nameV4
    - role: stack
      vars:
        virtualenv: venv_nameV5
    - role: stack
      vars:
        virtualenv: venv_nameV6
```

While they are only slightly different, they change how Ansible treats default variables (defined in `defaults/main.yml`):

If you leave a variable out when including the role in your playbook, Ansible will use the variable from the previous run of the same role ("variable bleeding").

In the context of the accepted answer, when not setting `virtualenv: venv_nameV6` in the last call to the `stack` role, `virtualenv` will have the value `venv_nameV5` (from the previous call to the `stack` role), no matter what `virtualenv` is set to in the role's `defaults/main.yml` file.

If you call your roles like I did in the corrected answer, your role's `defaults/main.yml` file will be respected and `virtualenv` will be set to whatever you have defined as default.

A minor difference, but quite hard to track down.

Comment: Sorry, but while you are not generally wrong, the description in this answer looks half-baked and is misleading in effect. Please do some more tests. ・・・Overall, this is not what the question was about - you tried to answer - then figured out your own answer had flaws - if you had just replaced it, it would be ok, but instead you started to explain why you were wrong - and that description is far from being correct.・・・For example: check what happens if you remove `vars:` not from the last declaration, but from a previous one, leaving the last one - will it still be "*from the previous call*"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right — it's not what the question was about. I added a dedicated answer because it is not possible to properly format code blocks in comments (linebreaks are removed). That's why I commented the accepted answer and started my own with "… here is the accepted answer written in pure YAML instead of JSON". **As for the actual answer:** It would be nice if you could point out what exactly is wrong instead of letting me figure it out if you already know — I am happy to edit it.

Comment: this was the explanation I was looking for .. "variable bleeding" !!